# Photographing the starry night sky

Tags: combinatorics

In the night, stars in the sky are seen in different time intervals. Suppose for every $k$ stars ($k>1$), at least $2$ of them can be seen in one moment. Prove that we can photograph $k-1$ pictures from the sky such that each of the mentioned stars is seen in at least one of the pictures.
(The number of stars is finite. Define the moments that the $n^{th}$ star is seen as $[a_n,b_n]$ that $a_n<b_n$.)

The problem has a nice solution using induction on $k$. Our teacher told us to find a solution using induction on number of stars. Can you help me?

[source: 2nd round of Iranian Mathematics Olympiad]

Comment: Maybe use a title that reflects the problem, not its source?

Comment: 1. How many stars are you trying to photograph? All $n$ of them? Or just a particular $k$-sized subset of them? 2. Is the condition that if you have $n$ stars, then at any moment, for every $k$-sized subset of the stars, at least two of the stars are visible?

Comment: @user326210 We are trying to photograph all of them.And yes to your second question.

Comment: Is the condition that if you order the stars by $a_i$, every *consecutive* group of k contains at least two stars that are visible at the same time, or does order not matter---all groups of k, regardless of when they appear, have this property?

Comment: @user326210 The order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

For the induction step, wlog. $a_n\ge a_i$ for all $i<n$.
By induction hypothesis, find  $k-1$ moments $t_1<t_2<\ldots< t_{k-1}$ to shoot pictures that solve the problem for the first $n-1$ stars.
Wlog. the $t_i$ are as late as possible, i.e., each $t_i$ is the right end point of the intersection of visibility intervals of "its" stars.
This implies that for each $i\le k-1$ there is a $j<n$ with $t_i=b_j$. This determines $k-1$ distinct stars (um, actually: this shifting may reduce the number of *distinct* times - but then we can in fact replace $k$ by a smaller number). Together with the $n$th star, there must be a moment $\tau$ where these all are visible. Clearly, $\tau\le t_{k-1}$ and $a_n\le \tau\le b_n$
It follws that  $t_{k-1}\ge a_n$, we can replace $t_{k-1}$ with $a_n$ and image will stil show at least the same stars, but also star $n$.

Comment: Can we reallyt find $k-1$ moments for first $n-1$ stars?The  induction just tells us we can do that with $k$ pictures?

Comment: I mean the $n$th star can have a period that another stars period contains it in that case we need $k$ captures to do that again.